# multi server framework suggestion needed

Tags: file, environment

Example, I have 2 server, each server using a copy of linux cpanel.

I first install free trial script into subfolder reside in Server A.

eg:

sample.com/service/username1
sample.com/service/username2
sample.com/service/username3

Then when people decided to upgrade, I gonna move all files to theirnewdomain.com, including database etc into Server B (another copy of cpanel).

In such case, what is the best suggestion to perform this kind of upgrade?

Move files from serverA to ServerB, possible to automate it? Zip it into a common place for Server B to pickup?

Moving mysql db created in ServerA's cpanel into ServerB's cpanel, best way? Recreate a copy into ServerB, then dump data into the fresh copy?

Seems like not possible to directly modify the db pointing in cpanel database, because its now 2 server, each server got a copy of cpanel. Things are separated.

Note, this process need a few task to be done in the process. Eg: update to centralized database of the file moving status, domain creation status, db creation status, and etc...

Any idea?

How actually other service that host in multi server work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you probably want to follow the pattern of running a backup script and then extracting it on the new server.  You may find some hints in [this description of a manual process](http://forums.theplanet.com/index.php?showtopic=62173).